# Has anyone used img srcset from html5 for assigning smaller images for smaller screens?

Tags: jhtml

Has anyone used img srcset from html5 for assigning smaller images for smaller screens?

I believe I saw it referred in one of the JoomlaDay Chicago presentations and took a note to look into it.  But I haven't found a good source on how the html code is formatted and used.  Does anyone have a tutorial?  And also, do you recommend using it - is it browser compatible?

Comment: Google says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images , https://html.com/attributes/img-srcset/ , https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/  In the future, please include your own proof of effort in your question.  Please read [ask] <- specifically the first paragraph.